Does action matter if the intention is to just take good action and not the action itself?
I like to try to be good and take the best possible actions for everyone always, but sometimes it's really hard and I get confused for doing it with good intentions.
If I simply like to be seen as someone good and take good actions even if I don't like it all the time, is this even OK or am I being selfish for doing it with other intentions, even if the actual action is the same?
(Excuses in advance because English is not my main language)

Cant make out what you're asking. Is it: "Are bad actions done with good intentions bad or good?"

Welcome to PSE, but I can't make out what your problem is. Why would you be confused for doing an action with good intentions? I'm sure that you have a definite problem in mind but your wording does not make clear what it is.  Do please try to reword the question. I appreciate that English is not your main language but anything you can do to clarify your English would help.  Best wishes - Geoffrey

If I may rephrase your question to understand it better (please comment if I misunderstood you):

If I perform an action that I think is a good action (i.e. the best possible action for others) although it is hard to do, BUT I do it out of wanting (i.e. intention) to promote myself so I can be seen as a good person, is it selfish, considering that the action does benefit other(s)?

The obvious answer is it depends on the ethical framework you use.  @JoWehler provided the Kantian framework while @SystemTheory gives you other possible frameworks.  Being a Aristotelian/Thomist I'm offering this common-sense ethical framework.
First, a few points salient to a Thomist way of evaluating a human action:

You identified 3 common aspects of moral decision making and execution: deliberation (using our mind), intention (using our will), personal-benefit (using our desire).
Furthermore, you identified the result of your conscience working (i.e. making you question your motive) as those 3 aspects become apparent in your consciousness as you progressed through the 12 steps of a human act (according to the Thomistic schema, hear this lecture, or see this rough description I found googling).
You also identified how goal (telos, benefits) DOES play a role in a moral action because the action results in a change in others and in yourself.

One evaluation is this:

A act can be objectively good, i.e. other people who witness the action, and with knowledge of the beneficiary of the action, can objectively say that it IS a good action.  If this matches what you subjectively deliberate whether it IS a good action, then you can congratulate yourself in discerning well in steps #1 (Apprehension of end), #3 (Judgment of attainability), #5 (Deliberation on means), and #7 (Practical judgment of choice).  This is a partial fulfillment of the virtue of Prudence.
Let's say you choose to overcome the obstacle (you said sometimes it is hard to do), then you can congratulate yourself in exerting yourself and taking personal cost / risk (i.e. you probably would rather do nothing).  This is a partial fulfillment of the virtue of Courage and Temperance.  The applicable steps are #2 (Wishing of end), #4 (Intention of end), #6 (Consent to means), #8 (Choice).
Let's say the action is NEEDED to fulfill a demand pressed on you by your conscience, say you saw a street robbery in progress and out of the many passerby who did nothing you saved the lady in distress, then you can congratulate yourself in your final push to perform a Just act, another of the Four Cardinal virtues.  The final push is represented by step #9 (Command) and if you are successful in preventing the robbery, then you have success in step #10 (Use).
But let's say you have mixed motives, you also want to be seen as a good person (or in this case, a hero).  In Thomistic analysis, this is a desire for honor, which is natural to be enjoyed AS LONG AS it is subordinated to the ULTIMATE end, which is Loving others perfectly, Loving yourself perfectly, and Loving God perfectly.  This is also where a Thomist would apply the natural desire for self preservation, for example, thus protecting the desire for good food, sufficient property, and desire to procreate (sex is good to a certain extent).  The stages involved are BOTH the very initial stages, #1 (Apprehension of end) #2 (Wishing of end), and the very final stages, #11 (Intellectual attainment of end, i.e. you're happy with your action) and #12 (Fruition, i.e. you enjoy the fruits of your action).
Please notice that those initial/final stages are only for you and God to see, other people (including the beneficiary) are none the wiser.  But it's precisely those stages that linger in your heart as effects of your action.  So if you love yourself, you want to purge the selfish element from your future action so you build up virtues (habit) in being a more loving person, which is a human being's ultimate end.  It's like practicing piano so one day you can perform a beautiful recital.  It is natural to desire honor, but it is better to do an act out of purer love.

Conclusion
Unlike the narrowness of the Kantian framework (which tends to focus on duty while neglecting love and denigrating pleasure), Thomistic framework does full justice to the happiness

of others (who benefit from our action), but also
of God (who loves all people and who makes a loving demand in our conscience) and
of yourself (who can enjoy doing good and work toward our own perfection which then makes us truly happy),

a happiness that in turn include those 3 elements (duty, love, and pleasure).
In the Thomistic framework it is NOT selfish to want our own happiness if measured by true love as the final goal, and to mix in appropriate honor in the process as a natural incentive.  Otherwise, competitions and desire for medals have no place in making this world a better place.  If you are a Christian, the Bible does say that God honors Jesus for his sacrifice on the cross (Isaiah 53:12, 2 Peter 1:17, Rev 5:13), so in being Jesus's follower, if your ultimate motive is to be honored by God (and sometimes by others by proxy), it is okay (John 12:26).

I like your rephrase. Is exactly what i wanted to say and thanks for the answer.
It helps me a lot.

@TSDrake I'm glad to hear it.  It gives me happiness to take the time to do this :-).

You ask: Is it enough to do good actions even if sometimes they result from a selfish will?
Kant’s  Groundwork for the Metaphysic of Morals  starts

Nothing in the world - or out of it - can possibly be conceived that
could be called ‘good’ without qualification except a GOOD WILL.

According to Kant the answer to your question is therefore: No, the decisive criterion is the good will.
But ethics is a field where different moral positions are discussed. For a first overview see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-theory/

A precept in Buddhism:

Do good, avoid evil.

The Doctrine (Principle) of Double Effect:
SEP Article - https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/double-effect/

The doctrine (or principle) of double effect is often invoked to explain the permissibility of an action that causes a serious harm, such as the death of a human being, as a side effect of promoting some good end. According to the principle of double effect, sometimes it is permissible to cause a harm as an unintended and merely foreseen side effect (or “double effect”) of bringing about a good result even though it would not be permissible to cause such a harm as a means to bringing about the same good end.

In part, Webster's defines prudence as follows:

Prudence - the ability to govern action by the use of reason.

Prometheus - Greek - Forethought. Prudence might also be defined as the ability to foresee or predict the good and bad consequences of one's actions or of the joint actions of a social group. One cannot control the intentions of others, but might have influence. So if I understand Buddhism correctly it holds that humans cannot predict all the effects of our individual or joint actions so we should intend to do good and avoid evil and live with the doctrine of double effects.
My observation is that political conflicts arise when people do not agree on what is good, or how to cause the good, when taking individual or joint action. In theory the intention to do good and avoid evil can improve outcomes for more individuals. Western philosophy explores similar ideas using terms such as virtue ethics, deontology, consequentialism, and utilitarianism.
